# Using Green's Theorem,calculate the integral....

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Using Green's Theorem, calculate the closed integral over $C$ $$\oint_C(3x+4y)dx+(2x-3y)dy$$
where $C$ is the circle of radius $4$ units,with its centre at the origin of the $x,y$-plane.

My approach: From Green's Theorem, $$\oint_C(3x+4y)dx+(2x-3y)dy = \iint_A  (\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(3x+4y) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x-3y)) dx \,dy$$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(3x+4y)= 4$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x-3y)=2$, which combines to form $\iint 6\,dx\,dy$. Now my question is that from the question what is the limit of the two integrals I am going to take, is it one integral from $0$ to $2 \pi$ and another $0$ to $4$ or something else...

Please see my approach and tell me whether  I am going or wrong or right??

Comment: Is the edit correct? and see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for using Latex.

Comment: Yup..It's cent percent correct...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is wrong because you applied the equation in Green's Theorem wrong.  Also, once you see that the integrand in the integral over the area is a constant, the integral itself is just the area enclosed by the circle times that constant.

Let $P(x,y) = 3 x+4 y$ and $Q(x,y) = 2 x-3 y$.  Then Green's Theorem states that the line integral over $C$ is

$$\iint_A dx dy\, \left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right) = \iint_A dx dy\,(2-4) = -32 \pi$$

Comment: Nicely done Ron. $+^+$

Comment: Thanks..i get it now...I just messed up with the signs in a hurry...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have $\iint \limits_A -2 dx dy$ just by applying [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), you forgot to subtract. Once this is done you dont need to convert into polar coordinates.

Hint: what can you say about an integral of the form $\iint \limits_Adxdy$. What does it represent?